W25Q16JV and XIP/continuous mode support (for RPi Pico)
My RPi Pico embeds a W25Q16JVUXIQ. Based on its datasheet, it does not support DTR or "continuous read mode" (which should allow reading without sending the command byte, by setting the M7-0 bits in the Read Quad I/O command (EBh))
However, the Pico SDK second stage bootloader attempts to configure this memory chip into some "XIP mode" also called "continuous read mode". https://github.com/rp-rs/rp2040-boot2/blob/main/src/boot2_w25q080.S
This mode is seemingly supported by the W25Q16JVUXIM chip, according to the W25Q16JV-DTR datasheet. Yet, https://direct.raspberrypi.com/ are selling W25Q16JVUXIQ chips, while stating they support DTR mode.
I'm very confused by all this: does W25Q16JV support it such "XIP mode" / "Continuous read mode" that removes the need for the command byte, or not?
Either:

It does not support it, so this boot2_w25q080.S file only works with W25QJV-DTR chips - maybe W25Q16JV has another boot2 file that I'm somehow missing.
It does support it, but it's not documented (or I missed it in the datasheet).

